# How to create a new shortcut key in onenote 2013 ? (i.e. page width to zoom)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zoom, microsoft-onenote-2013

As I'm using a tabletPC, copy/paste lots of images, texts, hand writing, 
 my onenote pages have different sizes... (using Onenote 2013)

Ideally, I'd like to automatically activate **adjust page width** ***to zoom*** for each page I select.

Otherwise, is there a way to add a new DWORD into the registry for that function ?